# Combine two dictionaries and remove duplicates in python

Tags: python, merge

Hi I have two different dictionaries. And I am trying to merge those two by removing the duplicates. These are the 2 lists.

```
x = [{'relevance': 0.722, 'type': 'Company', 'name': 'Dell'}, {'relevance': 0.314, 'type': 'OperatingSystem', 'name': 'VMs'}, {'relevance': 0.122, 'type': 'Technology', 'name': 'iSCSI'}, {'relevance': 0.266, 'type': 'Company', 'name': 'Force10'}, {'relevance': 0.327, 'type': 'Person', 'name': 'Greg Althaus'}, {'relevance': 0.085, 'type': 'URL', 'name': 'http://Dell.com/OpenStack'}, {'relevance': 0.174, 'type': 'Company', 'name': 'Storage Hardware'}]
y = [{'relevance': u'0.874065', 'type': u'Company', 'name': u'Dell'}, {'relevance': u'0.522169', 'type': u'OperatingSystem', 'name': u'VMs'}, {'relevance': u'0.444586', 'type': u'Person', 'name': u'Rob Hirschfeld'}, {'relevance': u'0.413988', 'type': u'Person', 'name': u'Greg Althaus'}, {'relevance': u'0.376489', 'type': u'FieldTerminology', 'name': u'iSCSI'}, {'relevance': u'0.314059', 'type': u'Company', 'name': u'Force10'}]
```

I have tried doing

```
z = x.update(y)
print x
```

It gave me this error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'update'`
```

I have tried this

```
z = dict(x.items() + y.items())
```

It gave me this error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Then I tried

```
z = dict(x, **y)
```

It gave me this error

```
TypeError: type object argument after ** must be a mapping, not str
```

Then I tried

```
z = dict(chain(x.iteritems(), y.iteritems()))
```

It gave me this error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Comment: do you want to remove duplicate keys or duplicate `key:value` pairs?
Anyway, as you can see, you're declaring `string`s, not lists, remove the double quotes

Comment: x and y are both strings, not dictionaries or lists.

Comment: Code is indented by four spaces, normal text should not be indented. Please take your time to make sure that your questions are properly formatted, so that others can read them and help you.

Comment: When both dictionaries `x` and `y` have the same `key`, which dictionary `value` do you want to keep?

Comment: What do you think the error messages mean? They seem to be pretty clear to me. You are working with strings: `'str' object ...`

Comment: Thanks for helping. Sorry my bad, I have removed the double quotes now. I got this error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'" and "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'update'"

Comment: @ArjunKumarReddy your question is not specific. Like on what basis you want to merge lists. Make it clear in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wish to create a new list of dictionaries and wish to merge them by removing duplicates, this would simple work.

```
def DictListUpdate( lis1, lis2):
    for aLis1 in lis1:
        if aLis1 not in lis2:
            lis2.append(aLis1)
    return lis2

x = [ {"name": "surya", "company":"dell"}, \
       {"name": "jobs", "company":"apple"} ]

y = [ { "name": "surya", "company":"dell"}, \
    { "name": "gates", "company": "microsoft"} ]

print DictListUpdate(x,y)
```

Output:

```
>>> 
[{'company': 'dell', 'name': 'surya'}, {'company': 'microsoft', 'name': 'gates'}, {'company': 'apple', 'name': 'jobs'}]
```

Comment: Hi Surya, Thanks for the reply. I have tried this earlier and I have got the merged list. But I couldn't figure out how to remove duplicates based on a key.

Comment: Surya, I could remove the duplicates based on 'name' key. Here is the code..'getvals = operator.itemgetter('name')

z.sort(key=getvals)

result = []
for k, g in itertools.groupby(z, getvals):
    result.append(g.next())

z[:] = result
print(z)'

Answer (score 3):

You can transform the lists-in-strings into `dict`s keyed by the name, then update:

```
import ast

x = "[{'relevance': 0.722, 'type': 'Company', 'name': 'Dell'}, {'relevance': 0.314, 'type': 'OperatingSystem', 'name': 'VMs'}, {'relevance': 0.122, 'type': 'Technology', 'name': 'iSCSI'}, {'relevance': 0.266, 'type': 'Company', 'name': 'Force10'}, {'relevance': 0.327, 'type': 'Person', 'name': 'Greg Althaus'}, {'relevance': 0.085, 'type': 'URL', 'name': 'http://Dell.com/OpenStack'}, {'relevance': 0.174, 'type': 'Company', 'name': 'Storage Hardware'}]"
y = "[{'relevance': u'0.874065', 'type': u'Company', 'name': u'Dell'}, {'relevance': u'0.522169', 'type': u'OperatingSystem', 'name': u'VMs'}, {'relevance': u'0.444586', 'type': u'Person', 'name': u'Rob Hirschfeld'}, {'relevance': u'0.413988', 'type': u'Person', 'name': u'Greg Althaus'}, {'relevance': u'0.376489', 'type': u'FieldTerminology', 'name': u'iSCSI'}, {'relevance': u'0.314059', 'type': u'Company', 'name': u'Force10'}]"

        # make a dictionary with the names as keys
x, y = (dict((d['name'], d) 
            # after loading the lists out of the strings safely
            for d in ast.literal_eval(lst)) 
                  # for each of the two strings
                  for lst in (x, y))
# or on Python 2.7+:
x, y = ({d['name']: d for d in ast.literal_eval(lst)} for lst in (x, y))
# combine the two dicts
x.update(y)
```

Then, if you want a list back it's just

```
x.values()
```

You mention sorting in your title. If you want to sort that list by name:

```
import operator
sorted(x.itervalues(), key = operator.itemgetter('name'))
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to be aware of is that you don't have two different dictionaries. You have two different *lists* of dictionaries. The second is that you don't explain exactly what counts as a duplicate. The third is that you don't say what to do with the `relevance` key.

I'll assume that two dictionaries with equivalent `type` and `name` keys are identical, and that you want the `relevance` values to be merged into a list. Then later you could average them, or whatever.

```
def gen_key(d):
    return (d['name'], d['type'])

def merge_dupes(dlist):
    relevance = [float(d['relevance']) for d in dlist]
    name, type = dlist[0]['name'], dlist[0]['type']
    return {'name':name, 'type':type, 'relevance':relevance}

to_merge = {}
for l in (x, y):
    for d in l:
        to_merge.setdefault(gen_key(d), []).append(d)

# if you want another list
merged_list = [merge_dupes(l) for l in to_merge.itervalues()]

# if you'd prefer a dictionary
merged_dict = dict((k, merge_dupes(v)) for k, v in to_merge.iteritems())
```

Output:

```
>>> pprint(merged_list)
[{'name': u'Rob Hirschfeld',
  'relevance': [0.44458599999999998],
  'type': u'Person'},
 {'name': 'VMs',
  'relevance': [0.314, 0.52216899999999999],
  'type': 'OperatingSystem'},
 {'name': 'Greg Althaus',
  'relevance': [0.32700000000000001, 0.41398800000000002],
  'type': 'Person'},
 {'name': 'Storage Hardware',
  'relevance': [0.17399999999999999],
  'type': 'Company'},
 {'name': u'iSCSI',
  'relevance': [0.37648900000000002],
  'type': u'FieldTerminology'},
 {'name': 'Force10',
  'relevance': [0.26600000000000001, 0.31405899999999998],
  'type': 'Company'},
 {'name': 'http://Dell.com/OpenStack',
  'relevance': [0.085000000000000006],
  'type': 'URL'},
 {'name': 'Dell',
  'relevance': [0.72199999999999998, 0.87406499999999998],
  'type': 'Company'},
 {'name': 'iSCSI', 'relevance': [0.122], 'type': 'Technology'}]
>>> pprint(merged_dict)
{('Dell', 'Company'): {'name': 'Dell',
                       'relevance': [0.72199999999999998,
                                     0.87406499999999998],
                       'type': 'Company'},
 ('Force10', 'Company'): {'name': 'Force10',
                          'relevance': [0.26600000000000001,
                                        0.31405899999999998],
                          'type': 'Company'},
 ('Greg Althaus', 'Person'): {'name': 'Greg Althaus',
                              'relevance': [0.32700000000000001,
                                            0.41398800000000002],
                              'type': 'Person'},
 (u'Rob Hirschfeld', u'Person'): {'name': u'Rob Hirschfeld',
                                  'relevance': [0.44458599999999998],
                                  'type': u'Person'},
 ('Storage Hardware', 'Company'): {'name': 'Storage Hardware',
                                   'relevance': [0.17399999999999999],
                                   'type': 'Company'},
 ('VMs', 'OperatingSystem'): {'name': 'VMs',
                              'relevance': [0.314, 0.52216899999999999],
                              'type': 'OperatingSystem'},
 ('http://Dell.com/OpenStack', 'URL'): {'name': 'http://Dell.com/OpenStack',
                                        'relevance': [0.085000000000000006],
                                        'type': 'URL'},
 (u'iSCSI', u'FieldTerminology'): {'name': u'iSCSI',
                                   'relevance': [0.37648900000000002],
                                   'type': u'FieldTerminology'},
 ('iSCSI', 'Technology'): {'name': 'iSCSI',
                           'relevance': [0.122],
                           'type': 'Technology'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initial errors are given because you have defined your dictionary as a string of a list of a dictionary.  Is there a specific reasoning behind this?

It will considerably difficult to do so as a string.

Try this:

```
x = [{'relevance': 0.722, 'type': 'Company', 'name': 'Dell'}, {'relevance': 0.314, 'type': 'OperatingSystem', 'name': 'VMs'}, {'relevance': 0.122, 'type': 'Technology', 'name': 'iSCSI'}, {'relevance': 0.266, 'type': 'Company', 'name': 'Force10'}, {'relevance': 0.327, 'type': 'Person', 'name': 'Greg Althaus'}, {'relevance': 0.085, 'type': 'URL', 'name': 'http://Dell.com/OpenStack'}, {'relevance': 0.174, 'type': 'Company', 'name': 'Storage Hardware'}]
y = [{'relevance': u'0.874065', 'type': u'Company', 'name': u'Dell'}, {'relevance': u'0.522169', 'type': u'OperatingSystem', 'name': u'VMs'}, {'relevance': u'0.444586', 'type': u'Person', 'name': u'Rob Hirschfeld'}, {'relevance': u'0.413988', 'type': u'Person', 'name': u'Greg Althaus'}, {'relevance': u'0.376489', 'type': u'FieldTerminology', 'name': u'iSCSI'}, {'relevance': u'0.314059', 'type': u'Company', 'name': u'Force10'}]

z = {}
for dic in x+y:
   z.update(dic)

print dic
```

Comment: Did you try your code? It doesn't remove duplicates, it just keeps writing over the same values, so you end up with just the last dictionary.

Comment: Yeah, I ran the code, but the author is not specific as to what he wishes to do.  I just wrote exactly what he attempted to do without errors.

Comment: He thought he had a dictionary of dictionaries (like I create in my code). If he'd had that, his code would certainly have removed duplicates, not done what yours does.

Comment: Hi friends, I have two dictionaries coming from 2 different sources. So, I need to merge these dictionaries and at the same time remove duplicates. I have removed the double quotes and tried merging, This time I got this error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'"

Comment: @ArjunKumarReddy Did you run the code in my answer? It works on the strings, or on the lists if you just take out the `ast.literal_eval(lst)` and replace it with just `lst`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. I could get the solution. Sorry that I couldn't explain my requirement properly. I wanted to remove the duplicates based on the 'name' key.

I have tried doing this. It worked.

```
def DictListUpdate( lis1, lis2):
    for aLis1 in lis1:
        if aLis1 not in lis2:
            lis2.append(aLis1)
    return lis2

z = DictListUpdate(x,y)
getvals = operator.itemgetter('name')

z.sort(key=getvals)

result = []
for k, g in itertools.groupby(z, getvals):
    result.append(g.next())

z[:] = result
print(z)
```

And the output is

```
[{'name': 'Compute Hardware', 'relevance': '0.236', 'type': 'Company'},
 {'name': 'Dell', 'relevance': '0.874065', 'type': 'Company'},
 {'name': 'Force10', 'relevance': '0.314059', 'type': 'Company'},
 {'name': 'Greg Althaus', 'relevance': '0.413988', 'type': 'Person'},
 {'name': 'Need to administrative infrastructure',
  'relevance': '0.292',
  'type': 'IndustryTerm'},
 {'name': 'Nova Volume', 'relevance': '0.101', 'type': 'Person'},
 {'name': 'RAM', 'relevance': '0.363781', 'type': 'Technology'},
 {'name': 'Rob Hirschfeld', 'relevance': '0.444586', 'type': 'Person'},
 {'name': 'Storage Hardware', 'relevance': '0.174', 'type': 'Company'},
 {'name': 'VMs', 'relevance': '0.522169', 'type': 'OperatingSystem'},
 {'name': 'http://Dell.com/OpenStack', 'relevance': '0.085', 'type': 'URL'},
 {'name': 'http://RobHirschfeld.com', 'relevance': '0.073', 'type': 'URL'},
 {'name': 'iSCSI', 'relevance': '0.376489', 'type': 'FieldTerminology'}]
```