# prepend to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, prepend

I have two lists (of dictionaries):

```
[{'code': '123456', 'reward': 'awesome reward', 'source': 'awesome source'},
 {'code': '12345', 'reward': 'some reward', 'source': 'some source'}
]
```

and

```
[ {'code': '123456', 'reward': 'awesome reward', 'source': 'awesome source'}
  {'code': '12345', 'reward': 'some reward', 'source': 'some source'},
  {'code': '54321', 'reward': 'another reward', 'source': 'another source'}
]
```

For future purposes I want the last object in the second list to be the 'new' object

I want to create a third (or new) list with the latest entry (last one of list 2) on top to be

```
[ {'code': '54321', 'reward': 'another reward', 'source': 'another source'},
  {'code': '123456', 'reward': 'awesome reward', 'source': 'awesome source'}
  {'code': '12345', 'reward': 'some reward', 'source': 'some source'}
]
```

I am able to merge two dictionaries using Surya's suggestion here: [Combine two dictionaries and remove duplicates in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890364/combine-two-dictionaries-and-remove-duplicates-in-python)

but this appends my new value. I am looking for some sort of prepend function.

Apologies if I am not clear.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have two *lists*, each *containing* dictionaries.

Answer (score 3):

Note that `list`s are very efficient at appending and very **in**efficient at prepending. You can however prepend like this:

```
list.insert(0, element_to_insert)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your ordering is with lists. You can prepend to a list by assigning to the `[0:0]` slice:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
a[0:0] = [4]
# a is now [4, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply concatenate the elements of the lists:

```
[x for x in d2 if x not in d1] + [x for x in d2 if x in d1]
```