# How to merge the values in dictionary without duplicates

Tags: python

myd is below

- I need to merge only the `role` key only without duplicates

```
a =[
  {
    'id': '101',
    'name': 'joen',
    'email': 'joen@abc.com',
    'role': 'Owner',
    
  },
  {
    'id': '101',
    'name': 'joen',
    'email': 'joen@abc.com',
    'role': 'Manger'
    
  },
  {
    'id': '101',
    'name': 'joen',
    'email': 'joen@abc.com',
    'role': '',
    
  },
  {
    'id': '101',
    'name': 'joen',
    'email': 'joen@abc.com',
    'role': '',
    
  },
 {
    'id': '103',
    'name': 'test',
    'email': 't@estabc.com',
    'role': 'Manger' }
]
```

Code is below

```
super_dict = {}
for d in a:
    for l, m in d.items():  
        super_dict.setdefault(l, []).append(m)
super_dict
```

My out

```
{'id': ['101', '101', '101', '101'],
 'name': ['joen', 'joen', 'joen', 'joen'],
 'email': ['joen@abc.com', 'joen@abc.com', 'joen@abc.com', 'joen@abc.com'],
 'role': ['Owner', 'Manger', '', '']}
```

My expected out is

```
[{'id':  '101',
 'name': 'joen',
 'email': 'joen@abc.com',
 'role': ['Owner', 'Manger', '']},
{
    'id': '103',
    'name': 'test',
    'email': 't@estabc.com',
    'role': ['Manger']}]
```

Comment: Why not use a set instead of a list? `super_dict.setdefault(l, set()).add(m)`

Comment: You could try using a Library to avoiding mistakes, try  https://pydash.readthedocs.io/

Comment: @Tomerikoo i tried but out is `{'id': {'101'},
 'name': {'joen'},
 'email': {'joen@abc.com'},
 'role': {'', 'Manger', 'Owner'}}`

Comment: So? Why is that a problem?

Comment: @Tomerikoo my expected out is different

Comment: @Tomerikoo i only need to append role without duplicates

Comment: What if there are two different ids in `a`?

Comment: if its same only i need to append, otherwise not append

Comment: For starters your current output is a dict while your expected output is a list... Maybe start by trying to face that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine two dictionaries and remove duplicates in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890364/combine-two-dictionaries-and-remove-duplicates-in-python)

Comment: @miken32 why you close the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many solutions are using nested loops. However, you can use a different solution using the code below.

First turn the original list in a dict

```
temp_dict = dict()

for item in a:
    if temp_dict.get(item["id"]) is None:
        temp_dict[item["id"]] = {k: v for k, v in item.items() if k != "role"}
        temp_dict[item["id"]]['role'] = set()
        temp_dict[item["id"]]['role'].add(item['role'])
    else:
        temp_dict[item["id"]]['role'].add(item['role'])
```

Then use a simple list comprehension. Like so -

```
final_list = [v for _, v in temp_dict.items()]
```

Now if you print that, you will get

```
[{'id': '101',
  'name': 'joen',
  'email': 'joen@abc.com',
  'role': {'', 'Manger', 'Owner'}},
 {'id': '103', 'name': 'test', 'email': 't@estabc.com', 'role': {'Manger'}}]
```

Is that what you are looking for?

---------------- EDIT -----------

As you wanted a list instead of a set, here is what you can do

```
final_list = []

for _, v in temp_dict.items():
    v["role"] = list(v["role"])
    final_list.append(v)
```

Comment: can you change 'role': {'Manger'} to 'role': ['Manger'] basically set to list

Comment: temp_dict = {}

for item in a:
    if temp_dict.get(item["id"]) is None:
        temp_dict[item["id"]] = {k: v for k, v in item.items() if k != "role"}
        temp_dict[item["id"]]['role'] = list(set())
        temp_dict[item["id"]]['role'].append(item['role'])
    else:
        temp_dict[item["id"]]['role'].append(item['role'])
final_list = [v for _, v in temp_dict.items()]
final_list

Comment: added the answer in comment, please change

Comment: but duplicates role is coming in the code

Comment: Yes, because you have change the set to list. set has the property not to allow duplicate, that is why it was used. If you want to use list instead then avoid the last list comprehension and write an explicit for loop where, before appending to the list you turn the set to list

Comment: I have added a new part to convert the set to list. Please check

Comment: can you tell me the logic of if temp_dict.get(item["id"]) is None:

Comment: It simply checks if that key (in this case that is the ID of the person) is already present in the dict we are building or not. If not then it creates a new record. If it is already present then it just adds to the existing record.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a basic solution.

```py
a =[
  {
    'id': '101',
    'name': 'joen',
    'email': 'joen@abc.com',
    'role': 'Owner',
    
  },
  {
    'id': '101',
    'name': 'joen',
    'email': 'joen@abc.com',
    'role': 'Manger'
    
  },
  {
    'id': '101',
    'name': 'joen',
    'email': 'joen@abc.com',
    'role': '',
    
  },
  {
    'id': '101',
    'name': 'joen',
    'email': 'joen@abc.com',
    'role': '',
    
  }
]

super_dict = {
    'id':'101',
    'name': 'joen',
    'email': 'joen@abc.com',
    'role': []
}

for d in a:
    for k in d.keys():  
        if super_dict[k] == d[k] and d['role'] not in super_dict['role']:
            super_dict['role'].append(d['role'])

print(super_dict)
```

##### Output

Note - this gives the output same as the question's initial expected out

```json
{
   "id":"101",
   "name":"joen",
   "email":"joen@abc.com",
   "role":[
      "Owner",
      "Manger",
      ""
   ]
}
```

Comment: expected out is different

Comment: I answered this before you edited.

Comment: Ok will update the answer, just tell me if the id's are unique.

Comment: not there will multiple ids

Comment: you get it wrong. I want to know is there any chance another object with name `Doe` will get the same id as `Joen`

Comment: no its not possible

Comment: ok so the solution I was thinking about is already given by @src. I think that's an efficient solution you may try.

Comment: But now this doesn't answer the question. Maybe it's better not to rush to answer and ask for the clarification of the question

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Pandas solution:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(a)
merged = df.groupby(['id', 'name', 'email']).apply(lambda group: list(group['role'].unique()))

merged.name = 'role'
output = merged.reset_index().to_dict(orient='records')
```

Output is

```
[{'id': '101',
  'name': 'joen',
  'email': 'joen@abc.com',
  'role': ['Owner', 'Manger', '']},
 {'id': '103', 'name': 'test', 'email': 't@estabc.com', 'role': ['Manger']}]
```

And if you want to stay in the standard library (same output, but slightly less flexible than the pandas version):

```
from collections import defaultdict

roles = defaultdict(set)
for item in a:
    roles[(item['id'], item['name'], item['email'])].add(item['role'])

output = [{'id': _id, 'name': name, 'email': email, 'role': list(role)} for (_id, name, email), role in roles.items()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's rephrase and specify your problem or task:

1. First we will use the terms "merge" and "duplicate" but specify the objects to these verbs
2. Then we will look for similar concepts from data-analysis and use terms from that to narrow down to a solution

The compass to specify and rephrase is your given input and the transformation needed to result in the expected output.

#### Specify *Merge* *Duplicates*

*Merge* the *duplicates* inside an array or list.

- *Duplicate*: To identify a duplicate we compare a *key*. An object is duplicated if it has the same key. This *key* is composed of 3 fields (attributes of an object):  `id`, `name`, `email`.
- *Merging*: 2 or more objects are merged by collecting the distinct values of a field (non-key): `role` (Merging also transforms the type: given as String in input but expected as List in output).

#### Rephrase using different concepts

So **technically**, in terms of data-analysis.:

- Some fields of an object form a *key*. An object is a "duplicate" of another if they are equal in their *key*.
- Objects can be *grouped* by a *key*.
- A group of objects can be *aggregated* by a function. Common aggregation-functions are (known from SQL) `count`, `sum`, `list`.

Side note: Similar to the concept of "aggregate" is "reduce" (like in "map reduce") which transforms multiples into a single.

Here "merge duplicate" objects means: group the objects by their keys and aggregate the distinct parts (non-key field-values) as list. As a result the "merged object" is composed for each group (as key plus aggregate).

#### Solution: group-by, aggregate as list

You could use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), see [a tutorial for `itertools.groupby()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/itertools-groupby-in-python/).

```py
import itertools
  
  
employees =[
  {
    'id': '101',
    'name': 'joen',
    'email': 'joen@abc.com',
    'role': 'Owner',
    
  },
  {
    'id': '101',
    'name': 'joen',
    'email': 'joen@abc.com',
    'role': 'Manger'
    
  },
  {
    'id': '101',
    'name': 'joen',
    'email': 'joen@abc.com',
    'role': '',
    
  },
  {
    'id': '101',
    'name': 'joen',
    'email': 'joen@abc.com',
    'role': '',
    
  },
 {
    'id': '103',
    'name': 'test',
    'email': 't@estabc.com',
    'role': 'Manger' }
]
  
# Key function: e stands for employee
key_func = lambda e: {'id': e['id'], 'name': e['name'], 'email': e['email']}
  
aggregated_roles = []
for key, group in itertools.groupby(employees, key_func):
    aggregated = list(group)
    # print(key, "aggregates:", aggregated)
    merged_employee = key
    merged_employee['role'] = [e['role'] for e in aggregated]  # list-comprehension to extract the role of each element (map) and collect as list (reduce)
    aggregated_roles.append(merged_employee)
print(aggregated_roles)
```

Prints this list with roles aggregated (line-breaks added by me):

```json
[
{'id': '101', 'name': 'joen', 'email': 'joen@abc.com', 'role': ['Owner', 'Manger', '', '']}, 
{'id': '103', 'name': 'test', 'email': 't@estabc.com', 'role': ['Manger']}
]
```

Try it online: [demo on IDEone](https://ideone.com/rAz2xh).

Note: you could also filter empty or blank roles out.

Comment: can you write code

Comment: This answer is less clear and much more vague than the question... If you think a question is not clear - don't answer...

Comment: @Tomerikoo It's missing code, but for some it _seems clear__: the terms _group-by_, _key_ and _aggregate_ are anything else than vague. Actually they can be found in a code-only [upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69003179/5730279). Yes, I think if the OP would rethink or re-formulate the question - call it "clarify" or "rephrase" or ["face that"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69002891/how-to-merge-the-values-in-dictionary-without-duplicates/69003157#comment121952829_69002891), the solution is not far.

Comment: @sim code added

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would use a set (inherently prevents duplicate entries), but based on the comments you seem opposed to using a set, so here is a solution that just uses basic lists. Considering your use-case, I doubt you will notice a performance difference between sets and lists (because the number of entries is so small).

```
super_dict = {}
for dict in a:
    for key, value in dict.items():
        if key == "role":  # the role list cannot have duplicates
            if value not in super_dict.setdefault(key, []):
                super_dict.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
        else:
            super_dict.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
print(super_dict)
```

Alternatively, if you have multiple different keys that cannot have duplicate entries:

```
super_dict = {}
keys_that_cannot_have_duplicates = ["role"]
for dict in a:
    for key, value in dict.items():
        if key in keys_that_cannot_have_duplicates:
            if value not in super_dict.setdefault(key, []):
                super_dict.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
        else:
            super_dict.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
print(super_dict)
```

Output:

```
$ py main.py
{'id': ['101', '101', '101', '101'], 'name': ['joen', 'joen', 'joen', 'joen'], 'email': ['joen@abc.com', 'joen@abc.com', 'joen@abc.com', 'joen@abc.com'], 'role': ['Owner', 'Manger', '']}
```

Comment: expected out is different